# cell detailTextLable not showing numbers properly

Tags: iphone, uitableview, nsdate, nsdateformatter, ios6

When I try to show dates inside a UITableView cell as a detailTextLable I get the number separated by extra spaces as in the attached pic, although when I try to NSLog it it shows properly for example (Jul 19, 2012) shows (Jul 1 9 , 2 0 1 2) or (2 0 1 2 - 0 7 - 1 9) if using the "yyyy-MM-dd" format as attached. (code below the image)

[image]

Here is my code:

```
//Format the date
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
//[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

[dateFormat setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
/*NSLocale *usLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
[dateFormat setLocale:usLocale];*/

NSString *theDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:[occasion date]];

//test
NSLog(@"The formatted date is:%@",theDate);


NSString *detailText = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                        @"%@",

                        theDate];
//test
NSLog(@"The detailed text is:%@", detailText);

[[cell detailTextLabel] setText:detailText];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine, This is probably a font issue, did u changed the detailTextLabel font? (it looks like u did, this is not the default font...)

Comment: Yup. That was the problem. I guess 14 is too big or that the font "Geeza Pro" isn't appropriate for the cell detailText. Thank you.